Offset or no update in my Supabase DB in a Stripe Webhook
I'm working on a Next.js project with Supabase, my users can take one multiple subscription.
On my Stripe Webhook while a user susbscribe or update it's subscription quantity, it is sometimes not updated in my Supabase DB, sometimes there is an offset (with the quantity selected in previous update !?! ) and sometimes it works normally.
here is my webhook endpoint (without all the console.log() I tried...) :
import configFile from "@/config";
import { findCheckoutSession } from "@/libs/stripe";
import { getDateAndTimeWithTimeZone } from "@/libs/utils";
import { SupabaseClient } from "@supabase/supabase-js";
import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";
import { headers } from "next/headers";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import Stripe from "stripe";

const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY, {
  apiVersion: "2023-08-16",
  typescript: true,
});
const webhookSecret = process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET;

export async function POST(req: NextRequest): Promise<NextResponse> {
  const body = await req.text();
  const signature = headers().get("stripe-signature");


  let eventType;
  let event;

  const supabase = new SupabaseClient(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL, process.env.SUPABASE_SERVICE_ROLE_KEY);

  try {
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(body, signature, webhookSecret);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`Webhook signature verification failed. ${err.message}`);
    return NextResponse.json({ error: err.message }, { status: 400 });
  }

  eventType = event.type;

  try {
    switch (eventType) {
      case "checkout.session.completed":

       //....

      case "customer.subscription.updated": {
        const stripeObject: Stripe.Subscription = event.data.object as Stripe.Subscription;
        const priceId = stripeObject.items.data[0].price.id;
        const customerId = stripeObject.customer;
        const newQuantity = stripeObject.items.data[0]?.quantity;

        const { data: profile, error: profileError } = await supabase
          .from("profiles")
          .select("price_id, subscription_quantity")
          .eq("customer_id", customerId)
          .single();


        if (profileError) {
          console.error("Error while retrieving profile :", profileError.message);
          break;
        }

        if (!profile) {
          console.error("No profile :", customerId);
          break;
        }

        if (profile.price_id === priceId) {
          console.log(newQuantity, profile.subscription_quantity);
          const { data: updateData, error: updateError } = await supabase
            .from("profiles")
            .update({
              subscription_quantity: newQuantity,
              updated_at: getDateAndTimeWithTimeZone(),
            })
            .eq("customer_id", customerId)
            .select()
            .single();

        console.log(updateData);

          if (updateError) {
            console.error("update error :", updateError.message);
          } else {
            console.log("update succeed :", updateData);
          }

        } else {
          const { data: updateData, error: updateError } = await supabase
            .from("profiles")
            .update({
              subscription_quantity: newQuantity,
              price_id: priceId,
              updated_at: getDateAndTimeWithTimeZone(),
            })
            .eq("customer_id", customerId)
            .select()
            .single();

          if (updateError) {
            console.error("update error :", updateError.message);
          } else {
            console.log("update succeed  :", updateData);
          }
        }
        break;
      }

      case "customer.subscription.deleted": {
        const stripeObject: Stripe.Subscription = event.data.object as Stripe.Subscription;
        const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.retrieve(stripeObject.id);

        await supabase
          .from("profiles")
          .update({
            has_access: false,
            subscription_quantity: 0,
            updated_at: getDateAndTimeWithTimeZone(),
          })
          .eq("customer_id", subscription.customer);
        break;
      }

      case "invoice.paid": {
        const stripeObject: Stripe.Invoice = event.data.object as Stripe.Invoice;
        const priceId = stripeObject.lines.data[0].price.id;
        const customerId = stripeObject.customer;
        const quantity = stripeObject.lines.data[0].quantity;

        console.log(stripeObject.lines.data[0]);
        console.log(stripeObject.lines.data);

        const { data: profile } = await supabase
          .from("profiles")
          .select("price_id")
          .eq("customer_id", customerId)
          .single();

        if (profile.price_id !== priceId) break;


        await supabase
          .from("profiles")
          .update({
            has_access: true,
            subscription_quantity: quantity,
            updated_at: getDateAndTimeWithTimeZone(),
          })
          .eq("customer_id", customerId);
        break;
      }

      case "invoice.payment_failed":
        break;

      default:
      // Unhandled event type
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("stripe error: ", e.message);
  }
  revalidatePath("/dashboard/");
  return NextResponse.json({});
}


I've made research all day and I can't understand what's happening.
Which is even more crazy is that the select() after the update return me the updated data well done even while it's not updated on Supabase !
For exemple while a user has 1 subscription and choose to subscribe to one more, Stripe return the quantity of 2, I add it to the quantity variable, I update supabase and the       console.log(updateData) return 2 as well, and when I check to my DB... it's not updated !
